# What does the "0 ≤ K < N-1" expression means?

Tags: algorithms, arrays

Given the following statement:

> "A nonempty array A consisting of N integers is given. Any integer K,
>   such that 0 ≤ K < N-1, splits array A into two non-empty parts"

What does the **0 ≤ K < N-1** expression mean in this context?

Comment: Can you provide the reference to the original source like a url or the section of a book? Do we have enough context? Can you provide more context? Does it mean splitting the array $A$ into the first $K$ integers and the others? Or the last $K$ integers and the others?

Answer (score 4):

You have an array with indices from $0$ to $N-1$. $K$ is an in integer in this range, i.e. larger or equal to zero and smaller than $N-1$.

This integer splits the array into two parts as follows:

Part 1: From $0$ to $K$ (including K)

Part 2: From $K$ (excluding K, i.e. starting with $K+1$) to $N-1$.

$K$ has to be smaller than $N-1$ (and not smaller or equal) because else there would only be one Part (the whole array) for $K= N-1$.

Answer (score 4):

$a<b<c$ means $a<b$ and $b<c$.